# pass a structure from python code to a C library

Tags: python, c

I have a C library in which I defined a tree structure:

```
struct node {
    int * info;
    struct node *left;
   struct node *right;
}
```

I want to make a call of C functions from python.

I wish to know what possibilities do I have to reconstruct the tree in python, that is built inside the C code using the quoted structure?

I intend to use [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). Do I have a better module for this?

Comment: ctypes is one good way to do it

Comment: I never worked with it. I try it now. I wish to see whether I have a better solution, and to see a minimal code that makes the reconstruction of a tree...

Comment: Don't start learning ctypes by building trees. That's like learning to fly jet fighters before riding a bike. Build up your skills bit by bit.

Comment: I need to pass from C code to python, and I have some difficulties. This is why I asked here :)). I know C as well as Python well, but I need to pass from 1 to other now.

Comment: Yes, I fully understand what you need to know. I know how to do it too. But I'm advising you to learn how to pass simple structs using ctypes. And work your way up to structs that contain pointers. If your trees are large then maybe a C extension is really what you need because ctypes could get messy and expensive.

Comment: What operations do you want to perform on the tree in Python? Would it be enough to pass a pointer to the tree from one C function to another? Otherwise, if you know both C and Python; you could create a pythonic interface for the tree in Cython. Working directly with the tree via ctypes would be verbose and slow.

Comment: I need to create dynamically a tree , on which i need to make some fast transformations (in C) and some slow computations , in Rpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might check out cffi.  It's kinda like ctypes, except it's more API-level than ABI-level.  ctypes is ABI-level.  It's also quite a bit younger than ctypes, and isn't yet included with CPython.

You could also try Cython, which allows you to pretty freely intermix C symbols and Python symbols using a Python-like syntax.  You can use Cython to generate a .c file from a .pyx, where .pyx is quite a bit like .py.  Of course, you then create a .so from your .c and import it into CPython.  I've used m4 to create pure python and cython from the same file - it worked well.

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide a few lines of code that compile ans transfer correctly a tree with 2nodes ?

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) might be a better fit for you, which is a binary communication protocol developed by Facebook for various common programming languages including C++, Java, Python, Ruby ... etc (here is its [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Thrift#Benefits) for more details).

You might also interested in the following question asked in Stackoverflow,
[Thrift client-server multiple roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518537/thrift-client-server-multiple-roles), which includes how the client calls a function in the server.

**EDIT:** As thrift only supports common primitive types, struct, and three container types (list<t1>, set<t1>, map<t1, t2>), you need to work with pointers.   One way to work with is to use id to instance map.  For example, you can assign an unique id for each node and use id to refer to the left and right node, and have an int to node map to fetch nodes by ids.  Here is how the .thrift file of your node struct might look like:

```
struct Node {
  // a thrift struct is composed of fields;
  // each field has a unique integer identifier, a type, a name and an optional default value.
  1: required i32 nodeId;
  2: required i32 infoId;
  3: required i32 leftNodeId;
  4: required i32 rightNodeId;
}
```

For the function(s) you written in C and would like to invoke from python, you need to pack them into a thrift service.  Here is the service of your function might look like (sorry, I didn't know your function interface at the time when I was editing this answer):

```
service TreeStructureService {
  void processTreeNode(1: Node node);
}
```

If you would like to learn more about thrift, you might find [Thrift: The Missing Guide](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/) useful.

Comment: Hello @alinsoar, [here](http://diwakergupta.github.io/thrift-missing-guide/) you can find more detailed example on how to write the .thrift file to work with the structs and functions in C++. One thing you need to work with in addition is that pointer type is not supported in thrift.  One way to work around is to create an id for each tree node, use left_node_id and right_node_id, and maintain an int-to-node map in your C++ code to find the right tree node.

Comment: @alinsoar, I have include sample thrift codes for your node struct and a possible C function for processing node.